# Mejorar detección de bordes con OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, filtro

Quisiera separar objetos del fondo de la imagen para diferentes elementos de casa. El problema es que no se detectan todos los bordes de los objetos, lo que hace que encontrar el contorno de este no funcione como debiese.

Tengo el siguiente código que ocupa Canny como detector de bordes:

```
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

    # return the edged image
    return edged

image = cv2.imread("IMG_7121.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7),0)

auto = auto_canny(blurred)
edges = cv2.dilate(auto, None,iterations=5)

cv2.imwrite("edges.jpg",np.hstack([edges]))
```

Como ejemplo tengo esta imagen de entrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La salida de la detección de bordes que muestras parece absolutamente razonable ¿Qué es lo que esperas?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta que deseas? La imagen que muestras esta pasada a wb y te lo detecta deseas lbp? O comparacion con un template matching?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho , hay zonas en las que no se detecta el borde, específicamente en los bordes del objeto mismo. Necesito que el se encuentren todos los bordes para encontrar una figura conexa y con esto extraer desde la foto, la máscara del objeto en si.